# How to make a link work inside a clickable row

Tags: html, css, angular, sass

I have a link that's inside a table row and its clickable. How can I make the link clickable to where I am not clicking the hole row but just that link?

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. How do I get my tooltip icon to be able to click rather than the whole row?

### My code

```
<tbody role="rowgroup">
   <tr role="row" class="fd-table--row" *ngFor="let myData of myList; index as i"
                    (click)="navigate(i)">
     <td role="cell" class="fd-table--cell">
          {{ rowData.statusContent }}
        <div *ngIf="myDataList[i].myAmount" class="my-class">
              <p [innerHTML]="myLabel + ': ' + myDataList[i].myAmount">
              </p>
              <a [attr.id]="mySelector" [attr.aria-describedby]="myTooltip"
                                href="javascript:void(0);" class="tooltip">
                 <my-icon [myIconId]="myIconId"></my-icon>
              </a>
           </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the click event handler onto the tag you want handle the click.

```
<tbody role="rowgroup">
        <tr role="row" class="fd-table--row" *ngFor="let myData of myList; index as i">
            <td role="cell" class="fd-table--cell">
                {{ rowData.statusContent }}
                <div *ngIf="myDataList[i].myAmount" class="my-class">
                    <p
                        [innerHTML]="myLabel + ': ' + myDataList[i].myAmount">
                    </p>
                    <a (click)="navigate(i)" [attr.id]="mySelector" [attr.aria-describedby]="myTooltip"
                        href="javascript:void(0);" class="tooltip">
                        <my-icon [myIconId]="myIconId"></my-icon>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Comment: I dont want the click event to happen there. I want the my-icon component to be brought up not the navigate method

Answer (score 0):

You can stop the click event from 'bubbling' using something like the following:

```html
...
  <my-icon (click)="handleIconClick($event)"></my-icon>
...
```

```js
handleIconClick(event: MouseEvent): void{
  $event.stopImmediatePropagation()
  // any other logic here
}
```